# USE MySQL query in PHP variable but omit from CSV output

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql query that serves as the basis for CSV file output using PHP.  I have a foreach statement that makes each column in the table also a column in the CSV output.

```
foreach($rowr as $name => $value)
```

My problem is that I need to omit one of the columns in the query (`Img AS source`) from outputting as a column.

I currently am doing this for the MLSNumber value by using

```
foreach($rowr as $name => $value)
{
     if($name !='MLSNumber'){
        $csv_output .= $name . "\t";
      }
```

I've tried to updated this line like this: `$name !='MLSNumber' || $name !='source'` but it breaks the code when I do this and ends up showing both as columns.  How do I omit both columns?

```
$values = @mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT MLSNumber AS MLSNumber, ListAgentMLSID AS agent_ids, Matrix_Unique_ID AS mls, City AS city, PostalCode AS zip, REPLACE(PropertyInformation, '\r\n', '') AS description, SubCondoName AS neighborhood, ListPrice AS price, VirtualTourURL AS virtual_tour_1, Bedrooms AS bedrooms, BathsTotal AS bathrooms_full, ApproxLivingArea AS living_area, Img AS source FROM table-name WHERE ListOfficeName LIKE 'Company%' AND ListPrice >= 500000 AND PhotoCount >=4 ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC");

$row = 0;
while ($rowr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($values)) 
{
  if ($row == 0)
  {
    $csv_output .= "state\t";
    $csv_output .= "country_code\t";
    $csv_output .= "email\t";
    foreach($rowr as $name => $value)
    {
         if($name !='MLSNumber'){
            $csv_output .= $name . "\t";
          }
    }
    $csv_output .= "image_filename_1\timage_filename_2\timage_filename_3\timage_filename_4\timage_filename_5\tlink_url_1\tlink_text_1"; 
    $csv_output .= "\n";
  }
  $row++;
  $csv_output .= "FL\t";
  $csv_output .= "US\t";
  $csv_output .= "lreInquiry@my-url-link\t";
  foreach($rowr as $name => $value)
  {

       if($name !='MLSNumber'){ 
      if($name=='mls') {$jpg_name=$value;}
      if($name=='source') {$source_link=$value;}
                $csv_output .= $value."\t";
       }
  }
  {
      $csv_output .= "http://www.my-url-link/feeds/".$source_link."/rets_images/".$jpg_name."_1.jpg\t http://www.my-url-link/feeds/".$source_link."/rets_images/".$jpg_name."_5.jpg\t http://www.my-url-link/feeds/".$source_link."/rets_images/".$jpg_name."_2.jpg\t http://www.my-url-link/feeds/".$source_link."/rets_images/".$jpg_name."_3.jpg\t http://www.my-url-link/feeds/".$source_link."/rets_images/".$jpg_name."_4.jpg";
  }  
  foreach($rowr as $name => $value)
  {
      if($name=='MLSNumber') {$home_name=$value;}
  }
  {
      $csv_output .= "\thttp://www.my-url-link/search-results/?fullinfo=".$home_name."\tMore Details ";
  }  
      $csv_output .= "\n";    
}
```

Comment: For those who run into this I substituted && for || in the if != portion and it worked great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: Is there a way to adjust the `foreach` statement to exclude the `source` column?

A: No, there's no adjustment to the `foreach` that will exclude an element.

---

It's not clear why you would want to make that particular adjustment, since the body of the foreach loop includes references to `source` column (the name of the column in the resultset which contains the value of the `Img` column.)

```
if($name=='source') {$source_link=$value;}
```

If we want to omit that column from the line in CSV, why wouldn't we just skip execution of this one line:

```
 $csv_output .= $value."\t";
```

for the column name(s) we want to exclude.

For example, we could replace that one line with something like this:

```
 if( $name!='source' ) {
    $csv_output .= $value."\t";
 }
```

---

To answer (again) the question that was asked:

No, there is no adjustment to the `foreach` statement that will omit or skip some element(s).

Answer (score 1):

First thing is if you are doing a foreach, it means you are trying conceptually with all elements in the array, you maybe should use a while.

From my understanding of what you stated here and saving distances, you can try two solutions.

1. First Modify your query (SELECT aa,bb,cc, ...) such that the undesired column does not come as part of your results.
2. The other way is to try this generic form:

```
    $excludedColumnArr = array('source', 'MLSNumber', 'columnY', ...);

    foreach($rowr as $name => $value) {
      if(!in_array($name, $excludedColumnArr)){ 
        ...    
      }
  }
```

Hope this helps.